# How do I rotate a video in DaVinci Resolve?

Tags: video-editing

I am using DaVinci Resolve 15 Free version.
How do I rotate video in it?
I tried Clip Attributes, and I see an Image Flip feature, but not rotation.

Comment: Hi, this is an interesting question, but [StackOverflow is for questions about computer programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), so this question is off-topic here. However, the StackExchange network also has several other Q&A sites, one of which is [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/). This question [appears to be on-topic there](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @reirab they need methods to move questions. Not re-writing this one.

Comment: There is a method to move questions (called migration,) but unfortunately this question is too old for me to flag it for that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to place the media in the timeline, select the clip and pick the Inspector. There is a rotate feature in the Transform tab.

In detail (assuming you are in a project and the media has been imported):

1. Go to "Edit" mode (the Edit button is at the bottom of the window)
2. Drag the clip you want to correct into the timeline.
3. Select the clip.
4. Pick the Inspector from the top right corner of the window
5. You should see a Transform section on right panel where you can rotate/zoom.

After the rotation, the video might not fit the entire screen. You will have to zoom based on the ratio of project_width_resolution/clip_orig_width_resolution.

For example, I have an ipad video at 1440x1920. The project resolution is 1920x1080. I will have to  zoom at 1920/1440 = 1.33333

Comment: Thank you @John Lim . I can't even upvote your answer, which is stupid, since this is my question. Upvote yourself for me. Thanks.

Comment: when i rotate a 1920x1080 video that somehow had the rotate tag set, rotating seemed to scale as i rotated. i had to set zoom x=0.62, y=5.57 to recover something close to my original resolution (it's hard to fix it exactly because it was shot at night)

Answer (score 4):

I think I have found an easier and more precise way to solve the problem of the video not fitting the entire screen after rotating it.

If after selecting and rotating the video you go to the "Retime and Scaling" settings in the "Inspector", it is possible to change the Scaling to "Crop". In my case, that solved the problem (after spending a few hours to discover the setting...).

I don't know if this method may reduce the video quality. It seams to maintain it.

:)

Comment: Works for me! The  default value is "Project Settings", suggesting that you could pick "Crop" somewhere in project settings and not have to change it every time. But I couldn't find such a project setting. Can anyone else?